# python add string to list ,how to delete single quotes in List?

Tags: python, csv, single-quotes

I hava get a list of string and save to csv file

```
imagesList=['img/201507/27/e731.gif','img/201507/29/e771.png']
myCSV =csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb'))
myCSV.writerow([imagesList])
```

open csv file like this:

```
"['img/201507/27/e731.gif', 'img/201507/29/e771.png']"
```

but what I want to get like this

```
"["img/201507/27/e731.gif", "img/201507/29/e771.png"]"
```

so I change the code

```
import csv
imagesList=['img/201507/27/e731.gif','img/201507/29/e771.png']
imgList = []
for image in imagesList:
    image = '"'+image+'"'
    imgList.append(image)
myCSV =csv.writer(open('data1.csv', 'wb'))
myCSV.writerow([imgList])
```

but I get:

```
"['""img/201507/27/e731.gif""', '""img/201507/29/e771.png""']"
```

so how can I delete the single quotes(')?

Comment: Why do you need double quotes? Why are you writing Python list notation into a CSV file in the first place? Why not use `myCSV.writerow(imgList)` (note, no brackets!).

Comment: You should do `myCSV.writerows([imgList])`

Comment: @ozgur: or just not wrap the list in another list.

Comment: If you really want to get the desired output you should *not* use the `csv` module. That output is invalid CSV data, and no CSV parser will be able to read it. I suspect you perhaps want to produce JSON data, in which case the line should look like `["img/201507/27/e731.gif", "img/201507/29/e771.png"]` (no outer quotes) and you should use the `json` module to produce it.

Comment: because I need upload a csv file to a website and it can only recognition double-quotes.

Comment: @ivae: but that website surely does *not* need the `"[` at the start and the `]"` at the end?

Comment: Need,I mean that the website only can recognition `"["img/201507/27/e731.gif","img/201507/29/e771.png"]"` not `"['img/201507/27/e731.gif','img/201507/29/e771.png']"`

Comment: That's weird. What's the URL?

Comment: I want to write a android app ,so I use Baas as a Server like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/),I use Scrapy crawl some data save as csv file and import to the website,but the website can not recognition ,so I ask this   question

Comment: @ivae seems like you want json data , not csv, you should use `import json; json.dump(myList,open('data.csv', 'w'))`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to enforce the quoting of the fields written by the `csv` writer, you your answer lies in the [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params).

Give a try with:

```
myCSV = csv.writer(
    open('data1.csv', 'wb'),
    quotechar='"',
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
)
myCSV.writerows([imgList])
```

Comment: No amount of quote enforcement is going to do what the OP wants. They are writing the output of `repr(imgList)` into one CSV column.

Comment: That's why I said "I suppose you want" when tried to guess what OP wanted from the original topic "change single quotes to double quotes"; I though the goal was to ensure each cell were to be quoted. You are being harsh down-voting for that much, but it's my loss, i suppose i'll STFU next time i'm unsure about a question ;^)

Comment: Good try, but best to clarify stuff in comments :)

Comment: It can be tricky answering appropriately when the OP has an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).